# image is not saving to android device in Sd card

Tags: android

```
package com.lociiapp;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.example.imageslideshow.R;

public class recciverfullimageActivty extends Activity {
    String reccvierid;
    Context context;
    ImageView recciverimage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent myintent = getIntent();
        reccvierid = myintent.getStringExtra("reccvierid");
        recciverimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.recciverImage);
        String myfinalpathare = reccvierid;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), reccvierid, 10000).show();
        String imagepathe = "http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/"
                + myfinalpathare + ".jpg";

        try {
            saveImage(imagepathe);

            Log.e("****************************", "Sucess");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void saveImage(String urlPath) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "test.jpg";
        File folder = new File("/sdcard/LociiImages/");
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        folder.mkdirs();

        final File output = new File(folder, fileName);
        if (output.exists()) {
            output.delete();
        }

        InputStream stream = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            // InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(url.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream());
            byte[] fileData = new byte[url.openConnection().getContentLength()];
            for (int x = 0; x < fileData.length; x++) { // fill byte array with
                                                        // bytes from the data
                                                        // input stream
                fileData[x] = dis.readByte();

            }
            dis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
            fos.write(fileData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is My code I am trying to save Image which is coming from server we have Image Url . when i Run this Code then Folder is creating in Sd card But image is not downloading on Save in Sd care please help and tell where i am doing wrong .

Comment: post logcat. Are you getting exception. Also check  String imagepathe

Comment: have you give write external storage permission?

Comment: No Exception Some Warning are there in Logcat

Comment: @Anil May be you will get **Networkonmainthread** Exception.

Comment: Nothing there is In logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Call like below instead of `saveImage(imagepathe);`

```
myAsyncTask myWebFetch = new myAsyncTask();
myWebFetch.execute();
```

and `myAsyncTask.class`

```
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {

    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    myAsyncTask()   
    {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(webview.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading image...");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.show();
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
       try {

            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL("http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/286.jpg");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File myDir = new File(SDCardRoot + "/LociiImages");
                myDir.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(myDir,"test.jpg");

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0; 

                while ( (bufferLength = stream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }
                fileOutput.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }  
}
```

**EDIT**

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/LociiImages/test.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: please here where u save Image please look my code  i have applied ur logic but still not save only folder create while in Device 3g Connection is there

Comment: @Anil Can you post that image url.

Comment: http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/286.jpg

Comment: actully i want download server image in my sd card and from there we have display on imagview

Comment: @Anil I also tried that image image is not loading.

Comment: http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/286.jpg this image will visible to browaser

Comment: @Anil ya that's visible in browser but not in mobile. Try with some other image url.

Comment: that i have to download in sdcard

Comment: its visible on mobile also we have download and save image in Sd card

Comment: @Anil I get the image if you need that i'll post my code.

Comment: how to get that image and display on Image view from Sd card

Comment: @Anil did you get that image.

Comment: yes But i am unable to display that image on Imageview in my app

Comment: http://pastie.org/9377377 this code i have tried according to You image is downloading sucessfully abut unable to display that image in Our app it show following exception  http://pastie.org/9377266

Comment: @Anil Where is `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your checklist should be as follows:

**A.**  Make sure you have the right **permissions**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**B.**  Move networking and file IO logic to **non-UI thread**:

```
new AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>() {
    @Override protected Result doInBackground() {
         saveImage(imagepathe);
    } 
    @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // update UI here
    }
}.execute(params);
```

**C.**  **Do not read one byte at the time.** It is probably not the source of your problem but it 
does make your solution *much* slower than it can be:

Instead of:

```
for(;;)  {
   fileData[x] = dis.readByte();
}
```

Do this:

```
URL u = new URL(url);
URLConnection connection = u.openConnection();
byte[] buffer = new byte[connection.getContentLength()];
stream.readFully(buffer); // <------------- read all at once
stream.close();
```

**D.**  And , finally, consider **using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for the job:**

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Nowadays you just no not need to write that much code to get were you're going..

Comment: conn.getContentLength()  in this line what conn here?

Comment: I have to remove for Loop ?

Comment: coz am facing still compile time Error according to You given code for(;;)  {
   fileData[x] = dis.readByte();
}  Instead of:this